# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar un ID por otro valor al realizar una petición con comandos SQL?

Tags: sql-server

**Hola chic@s, tengo una duda, tenga estas tablas relacionadas, donde "Nacionalidad" es llave foránea de Paises, ¿Al realizar Select * from Autores ,cómo podría mostrar el campo descripcion de Paises en lugar del ID?"**.

```
 ************    ********************
 * Autores*      * Paises *
 ************    ********************
 * ID       *    * ID               *
 * Apellido *    * Descripcion      *
 * Nombre   *    ********************
 * Nombre   *
 * FechaNacimiento *
 * Nacionalidad *       
 ****************
```

Intente con esta línea de codigo, pero me lanza esto en consola: **Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Argentina' to data type int.**

```
select c.ID,Apellido,Nombre,FechaNacimiento,Nacionalidad 
from Autores as c join Paises as p on c.ID = p.Descripcion;
```

Answer (score 1):

Si la nacionalidad de autores equivale al ID de la tabla paises lo puedes hacer así,
haciendo el join con el id de paises pero seleccionando la columna descripcion:

```
SELECT c.ID,
       c.Apellido,
       c.Nombre,
       c.FechaNacimiento,
       c.Nacionalidad,
       p.Descripcion 
FROM      Autores AS c 
LEFT JOIN Paises  AS p ON c.Nacionalidad = p.ID;
```

Comment: Corregí el código para que concuerde con lo que se explica en el texto.

Comment: Luis, puedes ayudarme con algo más? Es que estoy tratando de que en una tabla web se muestre Nacionalidad pero no por ID sino por descripción, creí que con código SQL funcionaria, pero no funcionó mi idea :(

Comment: Muchas gracias @LuisCazares no me di cuenta del error de nacionalidad, saludos.